# In Angular website, get exact text inside <div> tag with Selenium & Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to get exact text inside  tag with selenium and python.

When I inspect the element, I can see the html below on the browser.

```
<div class="value ng-binding" ng-bind="currentEarning">£8.8</div> == $0
```

I have written the python code with selenium in order to get text as follows.

```
currentEaring = Ladbrokes.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@ng-bind="currentEarning"]').text
```

When I run this script several times, I occasionally get the result as `0` - this is not true.

Rarely I can get `£8.8` - this is ture.

I guess I occasionally get `0` because of the `== $0` but not sure.

How can I get the text as `£8.8`? - using regex? If then, how?

Comment: Can you confirm if the string `== $0` (which is present in the html you provided) is actually part of the HTML DOM or you provided us for guidance? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's happening may be because, it takes some time to populate the text after page has loaded, and it seems like you are not waiting enough.

you can use explicit wait to wait until element contains certain text.

For your case, following example might work.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-bind='currentEarning']"), "£"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

One of the reason to get improper results may be due to asynchronous rendering of the HTML DOM due to presence of JavaScript and AJAX calls. As you have taken help of the `ng-bind` attribute only so our intended node may not be the unique/first match in the `HTML DOM`. Hence we will refine our `xpath` to be more granular & unique by adding the `class` attribute along with `ng-bind` attribute and take help of `get_attribute` method to get the text `£8.8` as follows:

```
currentEaring = Ladbrokes.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="value ng-binding" and @ng-bind="currentEarning"]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.